# How can I run a command in the background and log the output at the same time

Tags: terminal, background-process

I want to run some command in the background, but at the same time I want to see the output to make sure it is working well.

I'm using this to do some action using `wp-cli` and save the output.

Comment: Do you mean redirecting / piping the output to a file?

Comment: To just see the output of the command while it runs in the background on your current terminal run end it with '&' on the shell.


Generally all the shell output still goes to the console that invoked it. and usually you have to redirect stdout and stderr for that NOT to happen.

Comment: Is this specific to `wp-cli` or is this only about stdout/stderr?

Comment: @NoExpert yes i habe a command with no problem just i want to save the output in the text file

Comment: @JannPoppinga no it's not just about ```wp-cli```.

Comment: Running `bg-process &` is what I needed to do. stdout of bg-process will be mixed in with stdout of current/parent process. In my case `bg-process` is pm2 and foreground is nginx docker ENTRYPOINT/CMD

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, "i want to save the output in the text file" and "I want to see the output" then the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout) will help.

"The `tee` command copies standard input to standard output **and** also to any files given as arguments. This is useful when you want not only to send some data down a pipe, but also to save a copy."

You can also read more here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html

To use gustafbstrom's simple example:
`program [arguments...] 2>&1 | tee outfile`

So, you can see the output of your command on screen and at the same time save it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating two issues "running in background" and "I want to see the output".

You have to step back and think about the problem more. What do you really want?

Form what I gathered, you really want to "run in background".

You can achieve both goals, but one of them has to have priority and be primary. Solution to other will be informed by that.

As "seeing output of a program" is rather trivial problem, no matter what way you solve it, see other answers talking about `tee` and redirections.

As I said I suggest you concentrate on "backgrounding" first.

First truth: you need to realize that there is no "background" in unix!

There is a concept of daemons. And then there is a hack of "daemonisation", but neither of those mean "a background".

The concept of daemons holds even today, but the concept of "daemonisation" does not! Today (ie 2022) we have all the tools to throw out retarded "daemonisation" out of the window.

Daemonisation is stupid and it was mistake introduced by BSDs, it should have never happened, and it confuses minds of neophytes for decades.

Daemon on the other hand, is simply a process, that does not handle only single user io and is not limited to single user handling and a user session bound (finite) timeframe. Daemon simply runs indefinitely, and often (but not always) handles multi user io, and is not bound to any user session. But "foreground"/"background" does not matter anymore.

So back to the original statement: there is no "background" in unix, there are only two possibilities: either the outputs and inputs of process are connected to a current (your) terminal, or they are connected somewhere else.

Processes that are connected to your current terminal (ie. "foreground" - but keep in mind that that is only your forground, Ben has different foreground, and so does Casey), will naturally end up being killed when that terminal disconnects. Thus anything that is not connected to disconnectable terminal is running in "background".

I hope you understood the matter, and are not confused. If not, reread above paragraph, until you get it.

So for the "backrounding", you simply have to ensure, that your running `wp-cli` instance is not connected to any ephemeral terminal.

Terminal emulator terminals, VT login terminals and SSH login terminals are ephemeral, i.e. they are disconnectable. So all you need to do, is to "bind" your `wp-cli` to some non-ephemeral terminal, i.e. one that won't be disconnected automatically. Easiest ones to get running are `tmux` and `screen`.

So you login to your server, start new `tmux` session and start `wp-cli` from there. If your SSH session fails (a network problem), yout `wp-cli` will still run unaffected, because it is connected to "internal" `tmux` terminal and not SSH one (that one got destroyed when the network failed). Thus you effectively achieved "backgrounding".

Now unless you want to archive the output, you don't need anything else, as `tmux` has scrollback feature, so you can scroll back (pun intended) through all the lines `wp-cli` produced (of course tmux limits the number of lines recorded).

If you really want to archive the output, just `wp-cli | tee wp-cli.log` it form WITHIN the `tmux` session and now you can "watch and record" the output at the same time.

`screen` is similar to `tmux`, but older and more retarded, so I suggest you to look into `tmux`. On the onother hand, `screen` (in various stages of breakage) is present on more systems. Choice is yours.

`tmux` is a great "platform" for running long ad-hoc tasks in "background", exactly the way you are asking for.

Unfortunately sometimes, as `tmux` is so ad-hoc/manual (for example each time the server restarts, you have to setup the `tmux` session anew and start a command there), you want to convert your script to a "daemon", but that is beyond the scope of this answer article.